# Can we control case sensitivity of contents in .dockerignore file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, dockerignore

In the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) I could not find information regarding case sensitivity of contents in the `.dockerignore` file.

Can we control case sensitivity of contents in .dockerignore file?

For example: I have file extension like .txt, .TXT, .Txt - I would like to single specify pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `.dockerignore` file is case-insensitive on Windows and case-sensitive on Linux (and thus likely MacOS).

From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

> The CLI interprets the .dockerignore file as a newline-separated list
>   of patterns similar to the file globs of Unix shells.
>   [...]
>   Matching is done using Go’s [filepath.Match](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) rules. A preprocessing step removes leading and trailing whitespace and eliminates . and .. elements using Go’s [filepath.Clean](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Clean).

It seems like aforementioned functions make use of Go's [`glob`](https://golang.org/src/path/filepath/match.go?s=1226:1284#L309), [which is case-insensitive or case-sensitive depending on your operating system](https://wenzr.wordpress.com/2018/04/09/go-glob-case-insensitive/)

Answer (score 1):

It's Monday 20 Sept 2021 and .dockerignore files appear to be case-sensitive on Windows. I had to change one of my exclusion rules from
`!obj\Docker\program*`
to
`!obj\Docker\Program*`

I'm using VS 2019 (version 16.11.3) along with VS Tools for Containers 1.0 and VS Container Tools Extensions 1.0.